# Mistake with my bootstrap

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am looking for why I get this error:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: Missing argument 1 for Controller_cee::action_fichestandard()
```

For this type of URL :

```
http://localhost/mycontroller/myaction/4/12
```

But having put this in my bootstrap:

```
Route::set('fichestandard', '<controller>/<action>/<secteur>/<type>', array('secteur' => '[0-9]+', 'type' => '[0-9]+'))
        ->defaults(array(
                        'controller' => 'cee',
                        'action' => 'fichestandard',
                   ));
```

And this in action:

```
public function action_fichestandard($secteur, $type)
```

Will not someone tell me where I made ​​my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Kohana 3.2, controller arguments were removed. You need to use request parameters as described in the manual.

Comment: Thanks !
For those who wants learn more, here is the link : http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters